# COMPACT /U command does not decompress large 25GB file

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2003, compression

I have a 25GB file that was incorrectly set as NTFS-compressed because the directory where it is had been marked as compressed when it was created. I am trying to decompress it. The file is currently in use by a Windows service process.

I tried using File Explorer at the directory level to clear the compression attribute; I clicked OK, but it came back in a few seconds. Although the directory was marked as not compressed, the file was still compressed and shows blue in the window.

I also tried using `COMPACT /U` - it also returns right away, and doesn't seem to decompress (although it appears to say that it did):

```
 E:\Services\MyService\Map>compact

 Listing E:\Services\MyService\Map\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

27518828544 : 21974568960 = 1.3 to 1 C running.mmap
      235 :       235 = 1.0 to 1   test.txt

Of 2 files within 1 directories
1 are compressed and 1 are not compressed.
27,518,828,779 total bytes of data are stored in 21,974,569,195 bytes.
The compression ratio is 1.3 to 1.


E:\Services\MyService\Map>compact  /u *

 Uncompressing files in E:\Services\MyService\Map\

running.mmap [OK]

1 files within 1 directories were uncompressed.


E:\Services\MyService\Map>compact

 Listing E:\Services\MyService\Map\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

27518828544 : 22014078976 = 1.3 to 1 C running.mmap
      235 :       235 = 1.0 to 1   test.txt

Of 2 files within 1 directories
1 are compressed and 1 are not compressed.
27,518,828,779 total bytes of data are stored in 22,014,079,211 bytes.
The compression ratio is 1.3 to 1.
```

Why is this happening? Is the system working in the background to decompress the file, or is it ignoring my request? This is Windows 2003 Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely just a matter of time.  You cleared the folder compression, but the file is 25 GB.  It will probably take some time to decompress.

Comment: You are right. It seems like it worked in the background and finished a few hours later. What confused me is that there was no indication that it was working in the background. COMPACT output didn't say anything to that effect.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the process that is actually doing the compression is Explorer.exe.  If you look at the task list, compact.exe only runs for a second and Explorer.exe's CPU usage will go up.

Comment: You should look at the HDD LED and see if there's any unusual disk access. Or open resource monitor (windows vista/7) or task manager (windows 8) to see HDD activity